# Chart.js not showing when i try to format dates

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, momentjs

I'm trying to create an html page that uses the Chart.js framework.
I'm not able to get the x-axis to be formatted as date (any date).
If I don't include in the options the `scales` object the chart is showing as below. However, when I include the `scales` object, the chart is not showing at all. Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
<div class="container" style="min-width: 500px; width: 50%;">
    <canvas id="PnLChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("PnLChart").getContext('2d');
    var timeFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm';
    var json = '[   {"ReportDate":"2018-01-31T00:00:00.000Z","YtD":14609547.9130000044},
                    {"ReportDate":"2018-02-09T00:00:00.000Z","YtD":-7823612.5760000022},
                    {"ReportDate":"2018-02-12T00:00:00.000Z","YtD":-8326611.3190000039},
                    {"ReportDate":"2018-02-13T00:00:00.000Z","YtD":-9144531.6940000001},
                    {"ReportDate":"2018-02-14T00:00:00.000Z","YtD":-8122732.6769999973}]';
    var json_obj = JSON.parse(json);
    var itemCount = json_obj.length;
    var dateLabels = [];
    var pnlData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++){
        var d = moment(json_obj[i].ReportDate);
        dateLabels.push(d);
        pnlData.push(json_obj[i].YtD);
    }
    var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels:  dateLabels,
            datasets:[
                {
                    label: 'YtD',
                    data: pnlData
                }
            ]
        },
        options:{
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Year to Date PnL'
            },
            legend: {
                display: false,
                position: 'right'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            displayFormats: {
                                day: 'MMM D'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    };
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config)
</script>
```

in the head of my page i am including the chart.js and momentum.js as below:

```
<script src="/static/ChartJS/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/moment/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

This is how the chart looks like if i dont include the 'scales' object:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve the issue i had to reverse the sequence of the script tags:
from:

```
<script src="/static/ChartJS/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/moment/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/static/moment/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/static/ChartJS/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

if someone can provide me an explanation, i would be greatful.

Comment: those are in the head element of my html page.

Comment: That's because chart.js is dependent on moment.js when you use the time axis. Read the documentation here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html Nice find!

Comment: "The stand-alone build includes Chart.js as well as the color parsing library. If this version is used, you are required to include Moment.js before Chart.js for the functionality of the time axis."

Comment: Please mark this question as answered so others can move on

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me.

There issue is your `json` variable is split into multiple lines. Connect them into one line or change it to a multiline string with backticks.

Fiddle of your own code working here: https://jsfiddle.net/efq6wnhm/1/

This fiddle is using Chart.js 2.7.3 linked here: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js

Comment: Actually i have formatted my json like this just to post it on the question. In the actual page is one line, in fact it is created dynamically

Comment: If your data is being served dynamically there might be something wrong there and `scales` can't convert it. Try `console.log` your data set to see what might be off. Your actual `Chart.js` code is fine

Comment: When i say dynamically, i mean my html page is created with jinja. What i posted is the html page actual source code i.e when you go in the browser and do ctrl+u to see the source.

Comment: i don't know if it is my lack of knowledge in javascript/html but I found the issue, see my answer

Comment: thanks for your answer. By confirming that i do nothing wrong i started to look elsewhere.